# unable to upload file using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

i have recorded uploading and downloading file scenario in my work, am able to login and downloading file successfully but am facing the issue with uploading a file(Jmeter) also am able to uploading Folder but am not able to upload file into the application, while recording time it self am unable to upload PDF and Word document only text document uploading but it is uploading manually. can you please help me on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the file, you're uploading into JMeter's "bin" folder, this way [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) will be able to capture the call and convert it into the relevant [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler. See [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) for more details.

---

If you're building the request manually consider the following points:

1. Either use full path to file, you're uploading, or copy it to JMeter's "bin" folder
2. Don't forget to tick `Use multipart/form-data for HTTP POST` box
3. Make sure you provide correct `Parameter name` and `MIME Type`